# How to fix a "System call failed" exception when using Office Interop Excel and macros

Tags: c#, excel, vba

We have a C# application that executes a fairly complex Excel macro for reporting purposes. The macro runs fine for smaller datasets, however, when the data it needs to process becomes large, we get a:

> System call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED))   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.get__Default(Object Index)

after about 7 minutes of processing.

This is the syntax we use to execute the macro:

`excelApplication.Run(macroCommand, DataBook, DataSheet, macroParameter);`

...where `excelApplication` is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, `macroCommand` is a string name of the macro, `DataBook` is the Excel workbook, `DataSheet` the worksheet to use and `macroParameter` is just a placeholder parameter.

I have read about implementing `DoEvents()`, but unsure how and if this will rectify the current issue?

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: show at least the offending statement...

Comment: `excelApplication.Run(macroCommand, DataBook, DataSheet, macroParameter)` is the offending statement?

Comment: Keep away from `DoEvents()`.  Honestly that method should be stricken from the Universe

Comment: Okay, no `DoEvents()` then...

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht, what are the actual values of `excelApplication.Run()` call arguments when it errors out?

Comment: What does the macro do ? Obviously your C# part is fine (for smaller datasets) so you need to focus on the VBA being invoked inside the workbook.

Comment: @Robin, the macro loops through a couple of existing sheets in the workbook and then creates and formats new sheets based on the data found...insurance type of report so you can imagine the logic involved in formatting the workbook as a whole.
@User3598756, the values are unchanged and no inner exceptions are returned from the `Run()` method.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht, _"the values are unchanged"_ means that `excelApplication.Run()` statement is inside some loop and it gets executed _every time_ with the _same_ arguments? Or what?

Comment: No, the `Run()` method gets called only once, the loop is within the macro itself. So the method parameters stays as is.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht, then what are the specific values of `excelApplication.Run()` call arguments when it errors out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DoEvents() within the Macro itself, adding it at the start and end of each loop.